# Whenever I change function parse scrapy doesn't work or crawl?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, screen-scraping

This code works perfectly fine if I don't change the function parse.Then If I want to scrape all the content on the website then it stops working and doesn't return any query.Help me write rules for scraping.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()



class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mmt"
    allowed_domains = ["consumercomplaints.in"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=make-my-trip"]
    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("search=make-my-trip&page=1/+",)),
            callback="parse_items",
            follow=True),
    )


    def parse_items(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//table[@width="100%"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()

            item['name'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]//a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['date'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="small"]/text()').extract()[1]
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a/span/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            if item['link']:
                if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                    item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                yield scrapy.Request(item['link'],
                                    meta={'item': item},
                                    callback=self.anchor_page)

            items.append(item)

    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/text()').extract()
        yield old_item
```

Comment: yielding this Request for another one-liner callback is a strange idea. It does not serve much. Just modify the item the the `if` statement and yield it

Comment: @Marek not getting you

Comment: I   misread the code. Ignore my earlier comment. I've corrected the answer

Comment: What does this mean: *"if I don't change the function parse"*?

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth if we use def parse when using crawl spider it will overide it

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return items` from `parse_items`

Comment: for Page=1 if I change def parse it works perfectly fine,in order to crawl all the pages on the site than its not working if I change the def parse to parse_items or something else

Comment: Still my code not working have you tried at your end?

Comment: Nope I didn't run it. I went to scrapy docs about it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that ain't the problem I think here

Comment: Just one last comment, I had a problem with the `parse` method too. I didn't use (or define) rules in that project, though. What happened was that I had to have the `parse` method present in the spider, even though it was empty (the method), because I used other callbacks, like you're trying to do now.

Comment: I think I have written the rule also correct there is something I am missing,and that I dont know